# Import txt file in SPSS and save it as .SAV file

Tags: import, text-files, spss

I am trying to import a text file in SPSS to be able to save it to .sav file. The import itself is successful and I am able to see the data. However when I save the file as .sav from SPSS I am ending up with a file of 0 bytes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was save the .txt as .xls and then import it to SPSS and it works like a charm